# Share widget screenshot on web

Tags: flutter, screenshot, path-provider

I'm trying to take screenshots of a widget using the `screenshot` package and share it. I'm using the same code in their document to try and achieve this.

`path_provider` doesn't work on the web, so now I'm at a loss.

Comment: Is it necessary to save the photo that you want to use path_provider to share?
For example, you can use the capture method to return the Uint8List format and share the photo right away without any storage

Comment: From [this](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/933#issuecomment-1175865341) It doesn't sound possible